# iOS popup Cydia-like

Tags: ios, popup, cydia

How can I let my app popup something like Cydia's "Reloading Data"/"Loading Data" (like [this](http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/cydia-reloading-data.jpg))?

Is it a public API by Apple?

How do I call this?

Can I specify which image to display instead of the Loading indicator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it's neither a public, not a private Apple API - it's a custom control.

Second, why don't you just use [Cydia's implementation](http://gitweb.saurik.com/cydia.git/blob/HEAD:/Cydia/LoadingView.mm) itself?

Third, if not, [there are alternatives](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it adding an image view, a label and an activity indicator. You could even develop a subclass and upload it to GitHub!